# Angular 2: Creating a Singelton class HTTP Service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Currently I am Using **HTTP Service** in my Project , So I have to call the HTTP Services for every request, **e.g**

```
 this.http.get((`${this._getAPI}}`))
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => Observable.throw(err.json().error));
}
```

that is working fine but have to write it for every request , what I want to is creating a Singleton Class for HTTP requests that have the functions to GET, POST, DELETE,EDIT , SO how can I achieve the Singelton Http Service class so i have no to write these line again for every request just want to have some like this

```
HttpService.callTheGetApi()//its just dummy example
```

where HttpService should be Singelton Class having single instance.

Comment: Have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305876/set-global-data-to-property-from-get-request-before-continue/43307401#43307401)

Comment: Ok, so what does prevent you from writing HttpService class? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Create a service HttpService and specify its provider only in the app.module.ts. If you won't specify providers for this service in any of your components, whenever you'll try to inject it into a component, Angular will try to find its provider. Since it's not defined on the component level, it'll check its parent, grandparent and will eventually reach the root module where the provider was declared.  In this case, Angular will use one and only instance of this service that was created by the app-level injector.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service that wraps your api calls.  Something similar to this.

```
@Injectable()
export class BackendService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  callTheGetApi() : Observable<any> {
    this.http.get((`${this._getAPI}}`))
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(err => Observable.throw(err.json().error));
  }
}
```

Then (as Yakov suggests), provide the module somewhere near the top of your component tree, like a core module or your app module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ackendService } from './backend.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  providers: [
    BackendService
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in any component you wish to make your api call you would inject the BackendService.

```
import { BackendService } from 'app/core/backend.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-comp',
  templateUrl: './some-comp.component.html',
})
export class SomeCompComponent {
  constructor(private backend: BackendService) {}

  someMethod() {
      this.backend.callTheGetApi().subscribe(() => {
        // handle the response
      });
  } 
}
```