# Angular2, TypeScript, Ionic 2 code execution order

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I've got a interesting situation here which I'm trying to understand which is the best way to write this code.

I've got a service which I use to inject in a component to fetch data from the server which returns an observable.
Here is the code :

```
getDataFromServer(): Observable<any> {
    this.storage.get('access_token').then((access_token) => {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
    });

  return this.http.get(config.apiArticlesUrl, options)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError); 
}
```

So as you can see here this method is expected to return Observable. It also has a storage method being executed inside the method body which returns a promise with resulting data needed to fetch the data from the server using a Bearer token.

Now, Typescript complains that in this case the options variable is being undefined at this point because of scoping issue. If I defined options variable outside the .then(function) body then all the time options variable will be empty because of the promise execution and I can authenticate to the server because of that.

If I put `return this.http.get(config.apiArticlesUrl, options).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);` inside the `.then(function{})` body then TypeScript will complain that Observable needs to return from this method.

The important part is that I'm using import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
which whenever you use .get method it always returns a Promise which is not a good practice to change 3rd party core code.

The question is : Which is the best way to write this code so whenever I subscribe to the Observable I will get the user authenticated combining Promise and Observable?

I hope I'm asking the question in the right format and if it's possible to share some link where this is all explained in a clean way that would be very useful.

Cheers.

Comment: you should not use Observable and Promise together as both are two end points. You can see the best way in this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305876/set-global-data-to-property-from-get-request-before-continue/43307401#43307401) if you need more info let me know

Comment: I've just quickly updated my question. I don't think I will be able to implement the solution you've just shared with me since I cannot change 3rd party code in this case (Storage) from @ionic/storage module.

Comment: you can use the way of usage and generic way of handling services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I've solved this issue.

I've restructured the service method to look like this :

```
  getDataFromServer(): Promise<any> {
      return this.storage.get('access_token').then((access_token) => {
             let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token });
             let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

             return this.http.get(config.apiArticlesUrl, options);
     });
   }
```

And the place where I wanted this to be executed I've used this code :

```
this.dataService.getDataFromServer().then(
  (data) => {
    console.log("data:",data);
    data.subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log("This is the data : ", data);
    },
     (err) => console.log("err :",err)
    )
  },
     (err)=>console.log("err",err)
  )
```

And it works great. Still I can't say that the commented solution is not a good (better practice to implement) however since there are different types of situations I wanted to share this type of solution.