# How to add header to a post request in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-http

```
//In services.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

constructor(private http: Http) {   }
fetch(){
   return this.http.get('json-object-link').map(
      (res) => res.json()
    )
       }

 }

//In component

 ngOnInit() {

 this.dataService.fetch()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => this.ninjas = data
    );
}
```

> I want to add the following header to this request:
>   "headers": 
> {
>    "content-type": "application/json",
>       "access_token": "abcd"
>     }

Comment: you can wrap the functionalities by creating a cutom http service. refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305876/set-global-data-to-property-from-get-request-before-continue/43307401#43307401)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor (private http:HttpClient) {}

    getUserByName(username: string) {
        let url="http://localhost:8088/rest/user/userName";
        let header=new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 
            'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem("access_token")});
        return this.http.post(url, username, {headers: header});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 let headers = new Headers({ "content-type": "application/json", });
    headers.append('access_token', "abcd");
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

 this.http
      .post(url, data, options)
```

Comment: I helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers = headers.set(...); headers = headers.set(...); headers = headers.set(...);
```

or

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set(...)
                                     .set(...)
                                     .set(...);
```

reference : [issue with post request http header angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620304/issue-with-post-request-http-header-angular-4)

if in angular 2

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('authentication', `${student.token}`);

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http
    .put(url, JSON.stringify(student), options)
```