# How to load app.config.ts file when a component loaded in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

When I am login,I am setting the login details and token in localstorage and then redirects to employee component.Here for my API's I need to send token.I am putting headers and appending token to it in a common file call app.config.ts.

Whats happening here is..When I login then the next page is getting the employee list.Here the token is coming as empty from app.config.ts so then my API shows error {'token not provide'}.When I refresh my page,then its fine.Its been irritating for me since long back can anyone please suggest me help.Or did I need to put time out to call my API?
I have app.config.ts file,

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfig { 
    config: any;
    serverUrl: any;
    loginToken: any;
    token: any;
    imageUrl: any;
    headers: any;
    constructor(public router: Router) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.loginToken = localStorage.getItem('EmployeeToken');
        this.token = "Bearer" +' '+ this.loginToken;
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.headers.append('Authorization', this.token);
   }
}
```

I am using it in employye.component.ts,

```
 import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { AppConfig } from "../../app.config";

@Component({
    templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
    providers: [AppConfig]
})

export class EmployeeComponent {
    constructor(public _appConfig: AppConfig) {
        this.http = http;
        this.serverUrl = _appConfig.serverUrl;
        this.headers = _appConfig.headers;
        this.getAllEmployees();
    }

    // Get Employees
    getAllEmployees() {
        this.http.get(this.serverUrl + 'employees', { headers: this.headers })
            .subscribe(response => {
                if (response && response.json()) {
                       ////
                    }
                } else {
                    this.employees = [];
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305876/set-global-data-to-property-from-get-request-before-continue/43307401#43307401)

Comment: Put the code that you have inside the constructor in a method, and call that method right after you're logged in, when you know what the token is.