# Best approach for creating http request service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise, angular5, angular-observable

I created one service for handling all http request. It is working perfectly. But I want to know is there any fault in my approach and also want to know other good approaches like observable?

**request.service.js**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MessageService } from './message.service';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
};

interface IRequestOption {
    url: string;
    cxfgroup: string;
    endpoint: string;
    data: object;
}

interface IRequestBody {
    option: IRequestOption;
    log: string;
    error: string;
}

class HTTP {

    private messageService: MessageService;

    constructor(http, messageService, url: string, body: object, log: string, error: string) {
        this.callHTTP(http, url, body, log, error);
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

    callHTTP(http, url, body, log, error) {
        return http.post(url, body, httpOptions).toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        // let body = res.json();
        // return body['data'] || {};
        return res || {};
    }

    private handleErrorPromise(error: Response | any) {
        console.error(error.message || error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}

class RequestFactory {
    private baseURL = 'https://app.domain.com/cxf/';
    /**
     * CXF ENPOINTS
     */
    private endpoints: any = {
        "auth": {
            "getcustomerkeys": "auth/getcustomerkeys"
        }
    };

    call(http, messageService, options: IRequestOption, log: string, error: string) {
        let url: string = options.url ? options.url : this.baseURL;
        if (this.endpoints.hasOwnProperty(options['cxfgroup'])) {
            url += this.endpoints[options.cxfgroup][options.endpoint];
        }

        return new HTTP(http, messageService, url, options.data, log, error);
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class RequestService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) { }

    post(request: IRequestBody) {
        let requestFactory = new RequestFactory();
        requestFactory.call(this.http, this.messageService, request.option, request.log, request.error);
    }

}
```

> I'm calling this "post" method using the following code. Here I want
>   to set a promise once the request complete i want to show some
>   message.

```
this.requestService.post({
  option: {
    url: '',
     cxfgroup: 'auth',
      endpoint: 'getcustomerkeys',
       data: {
         userid: 'user@domain.com'
       }
  },
  log: 'login initiated!',
  error: 'customerKeyError'
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305876/set-global-data-to-property-from-get-request-before-continue/43307401#43307401)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTTP Service**

Here is an observable based approach we're using in our projects:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  /**
   * Invoke function should be able to handle any HTTP request based on the @params
   */
  invoke(params): Observable<any> {
    if (params) {
      const method = params.method.toLowerCase();
      const { url, path, body, headers, query } = params;

      const requestURL = `${url}/${path}`;

      let request;
      let requestParams = new HttpParams();
      let requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

      /**
       * DEFAULT HEADERS
       */
      requestHeaders = requestHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      /**
       * CUSTOM HEADERS
       */
      if (headers) {
        for (const key in headers) {
          if (headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            requestHeaders = requestHeaders.append(key, headers[key]);
          }
        }
      }

      /**
       * CUSTOM REQUEST QUERY (?key=value)
       */
      if (query) {
        for (const key in query) {
          if (query.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            requestParams = requestParams.append(key, query[key]);
          }
        }
      }

      const requestOptions = {
        headers: requestHeaders,
        params: requestParams,
      };

      /**
       * HANDLE GET, POST etc. REQUESTS
       */
      if (method === 'get') {
        request = this.http[method](requestURL, requestOptions);
      } else if (method === 'post' || method === 'put') {
        request = this.http[method](
          requestURL,
          JSON.stringify(body),
          requestOptions,
        );
      } else if (method === 'delete') {
        request = this.http.request(method, requestURL, {
          ...requestOptions,
          body: JSON.stringify(body),
        });
      } else {
        console.error('Unknown request method.');
      }

      /**
       * RETURN API REQUEST
       */
      return request;
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage example in services**

Which is very simple to use in your service, so it's gonna look like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpService) {}

makeRequest() {
  return this.http.invoke({
    method: 'POST', // method like POST, GET etc.
    url: 'http://blabla', // base URL
    path: 'makeReq', // API endpoint
    body: ..., // body for POST or PUT requests
    headers: {headerName: 'HeaderValue'} // headers you need to add to your request
    query: {query: 'queryValue'} // URL query to be added (eg. ?query=queryValue)
  });
}
```

Please note that `body`, `headers` and `query` are optional.

**Usage example in components**

And finally, you need to subscribe to an Observable in your components to make the request:

```
this.yourServiceName.makeRequest().subscribe(
  success => {
    // handle success
  },
  error => {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

## Error Handling

To handle errors we can use [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses) so it's gonna look something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).catch(errorReponse => {
      let error: string;
      if (errorReponse instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        error = errorReponse.error;
        const { status, statusText, message } = errorReponse;
        const errMsg = `HTTP ERROR: ${status} - ${statusText}\n${message}\n\nBACKEND RESPONSE: `;
        console.error(errMsg, error);
      } else {
        error = null;
      }
      return _throw(error);
    });
  }
}

export const ErrorHttpInterceptor = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
  multi: true,
};
```

`HttpInterceptor` will apply some middleware functionality to all HTTP calls made with `HttpClient` provider. Please note it won't work with `Http` provider as it's deprecated in the latest releases. And don't forget to include the interceptor in `@NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [ErrorHttpInterceptor]
})
```

A similar approach can be used to inject `Authorization` token etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Libu, it's all more "simple" than your code. You don't need create class and class and class. Futhermore the best approach it's always return an Observable.Really there are no advantage to use promise instead of  of observable. If you return an observable you can "chain" (using switchMap), "group" (using fork), etc

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestService {
    private baseURL = 'https://app.domain.com/cxf/';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient)

    post(request: IRequestBody) {
        let url: string = options.url ? options.url : this.baseURL;
        if (this.endpoints.hasOwnProperty(options['cxfgroup'])) {
            url += this.endpoints[options.cxfgroup][options.endpoint];
        }
        let requestFactory = new RequestFactory();
        this.http.post(url,this.messageService, request.option)
        .do(console.log(request.log))  //when the request sucesfully
                                       //show in console
        .catch(console.log(request.error)); //if fail, show in console the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Sorry, But I have different methods like the post, get etc.. So anyway I need to separate that code.

Comment: @Libu Mathew, in your code I can't see the different methods :(

Comment: Yes. But I need all these cases. That's why I separated code.

Comment: you can make a "request" instead of "post" or add a "get" method in the Service

Comment: Yes I did like that.